# Make onSensorChanged not to slow UI

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask

My app acquires data from accelerometer and the UI is not so responsive as it should be.
I suppose this is because SensorEventListener is called in the UI thread. 
So I tried to create a new thread, with an inner class which implements the event listener and in the thread I registered the accelerometer.
Nevertheless the code was executed in the UI thread. So: how would you make onSensorChanged not slowing UI?

Answer (score 1):

Don't do a lot inside the callback. When you are executing your code, you cannot get another update.

For example, when you have a sleep(500) in the onSensorChanged, you will not receive a new update for the comming 500 mili sec.

So start a new thread inside the onSensorChanged and do your stuff in there.

Comment: In this way it would create one thread each time is called the onSensorChanged. It looks so resource expensive.

Comment: That's indeed true. But what do you need to do in this callback?

Comment: how about starting one thread to handle all sensor changes (if only the newest is important no queue otherwise with queue to work them all off) and passing the "new" data received to that thread.

Comment: I need to update some textview and a couple of seekbars using accelerometer data. The problem is that the onSensorChanged works on UI thread and I didn't manage to thread it in different ways.